# MySQL Where Clause error

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

i have the following statement

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from rests ORDER BY name asc WHERE flag = '1' LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

am getting the following error

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE flag = '1' LIMIT 0 , 20' at line 1
```

am not sure where am going wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have the `ORDER BY` clause before `WHERE` clause.

Refer to the [**MySQL select syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for the correct order of various clauses.

Try this:

```
SELECT * from rests WHERE flag = '1' ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Also Ordering in ascending is default, you may drop the `asc`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from rests  WHERE flag = '1' ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` clause must be after the `WHERE` clause. That's all it is.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` comes after the `WHERE` and `LIMIT` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` goes before `ORDER BY`.